# The development server returned response error code: 500 on a boiler plate code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, webstorm

I created a React Native app in WebStorm IDE. It's just default boiler plate code and I'm facing this error.

[image: Snapshot of the error.]

Can anyone help me out regarding this?

Comment: it is internal server error.

Comment: Can you suggest what kind of internal server error it maybe?
And what things can I try to resolve it?

Comment: Have you read the error and followed its instructions?

Comment: The error root cause including link and three possible solutions is IN the error message. Try to solve it by following these steps...

Comment: A 500 error means it's an "internal server error" and usually points to some code misconfiguration or dependency that is not installed correctly and is being called. Your way to resolve this is to take a look at the application/server logs. Because you have not given any specifics to your stack, I cannot tell you where your logs will output.

Comment: Can you guide where will these 'application/ server logs' be found?

Comment: The problem was related to the react-native version. I had to specify the version at the time of app creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to the version of react-native. In order to solve the problem I had to specify the right version of react-native at the time of creating the app.

The exact command was:

```
react-native init App_Name --version 0.55.4
```

I was suggested by multiple people to downgrade the react-native version of the already created project. I tried multiple ways but none of them worked.

[Instances of Git-Bash and Android emulator, showing a successful build.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwzM0.png)

Answer (score 0):

try closing everything and re-opening them and if that doesnt work type the following

```
     cd android
```

and then

```
    gradlew clean
```

then

```
    cd..
```

and finally try to run your app again

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this solution.

Comment: So I tried this solution and it didn't work.
I also tried few other solutions, just for the sake of trying but the same error every time.

Comment: Well if this didnt work I am quite sure you need to reinstall your dependencies because something is missing. npm or yarn install (depends what you are using) the third party libraries you are importing to your app.

Comment: The problem was related to the react-native version. I had to specify the version at the time of app creation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` to make a reverse proxy and connect your android phone to your node server